# Exception installing monolog in composer

Tags: php, composer-php, monolog

I tried to install `monolog/monolog` with composer `composer require monolog/monolog` on my Ubuntu but I got this error :

```
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.


  [RuntimeException]
  pathToMyProject/vendor/psr/log does not exist and could not be created.
```

Has someone an idea of what the problem is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my bad you just have to run has `sudo` :p

Comment: the error you have doesn't say that